# ReferenceError: data is not defined when writing a piped gulp script

Tags: gulp

```
  gulp.task('default', function(done) {
    inquirer.prompt([{
        type: `input`,
        message: `Enter the path`,
        default: `./admin/admin.json`,
        name: `path`
    }]).then(function(answers) {
      console.log(answers.path);
      console.log('answers');
      mydefaultTaskTwo(null, answers.path).pipe(pipedFunction());
      done();
    })

  });

  function mydefaultTaskTwo(cb, path) {
    let data = '';

    try {
      data = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8');
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
    }
    return data;

  }

  function pipedFunction() {
    let object = JSON.parse(data);
    object['main'] = 'admin';
    data = JSON.stringify(object);

    const readable = Readable.from(data)
    return readable;
  }
```

I understand that src returns a stream and pipe takes that stream and return a stream, but how do you feed in the stream into the `pipedFunction` called inside of pipe? I am unsure how it works. I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: data is not defined.

Is there something I am misunderstanding about gulp scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you define `data` as a local scope-level variable and try to reach it from a different scope, where it's `undefined`. So, you need to make use of the fact that `data` is returned and pass it, like:

```
var data = mydefaultTaskTwo(null, answers.path);
data.pipe(pipedFunction(data));
```